# Convert multiple Array object rows to one row, group by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have bellow array object

```
var dataarray = [{Region: 'Asia', Total: '0.50'},
                    {Region: 'America', Total: '1.50'},
                    {Region: 'Middle East', Total: '1.50'}]
```

i want to convert it like bellow

```
var convertarray = [{'Asia' : '0.50', 'America' : '1.50', 'Middle East' : '1.50'}]
```

i tried bellow way but it creates multiple rows even though groping by the region

```
    var result = []; 

    dataarray.forEach(entry => {
    let existingCountry = result.find(Region => Region.Region === entry.Region);
    
    if (existingCountry) {
        existingCountry[entry.Region] = entry.Total;
    } else {
        let newCountry = { "Region": entry.Region };
        newCountry[entry.Region] = entry.Total;
        result.push(newCountry);
    }
    });

    var alldata = Array.from(new Set(dataarray.map(entry => entry.Region)));
  
    result.forEach(Region => {
    alldata.forEach(month => {
        if (!Region.hasOwnProperty(month)) {
            Region[month] = 0;
        }
    });
    });
```

any other way to archive desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you're doing is mapping each `{ Region : somekey, Total: value }` object in your array to `{ somekey: value }`, which you can do in a single step by taking advantage of JS's bracket notation for property names:

```js
const data = [
  { region: 'Asia', total: '0.50'},
  { region: 'America', total: '1.50'},
  { region: 'Middle East', total: '1.50'}
 ];
 
 const remapped = data.map(e => ({[e.region]: e.total}));
 
 console.log(remapped);
```

Answer (score -2):

To convert multiple array object rows to a single row grouped by a key, you can use the `reduce` method in JavaScript. Here's an example of how you can achieve the desired result:

```js
var dataarray = [
  { Region: 'Asia', Total: '0.50' },
  { Region: 'America', Total: '1.50' },
  { Region: 'Middle East', Total: '1.50' }
];

var convertarray = dataarray.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  acc[entry.Region] = entry.Total;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(convertarray);
```

This will output:

```
{
  'Asia': '0.50',
  'America': '1.50',
  'Middle East': '1.50'
}
```

In the code above, we use the `reduce` method to iterate over the `dataarray` and accumulate the desired result in the `convertarray` object. For each entry, we assign the `Total` value to the corresponding `Region` key in the `convertarray` object.

This approach eliminates the need for additional loops and checks for existing countries. The `reduce` method simplifies the code and provides a more concise solution.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.